# Arrows not showing in Lato

Tags: css, fonts, character-encoding, google-webfonts

I have this:

#### ← Medical Device Solutions

However, the arrow is not displayed when using Lato as:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">`

I also have, just in case:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

The arrow character is displayed as a strange symbol. What could be the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: That font family doesn't have that glyph (character) is usually what that means. Not every font has every character. On the [font page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato) you can see all the characters included in that font... that arrow is not represented

Comment: what are using for the arrow...could you provide a working code..

Answer (score 0):

works for me maybe you have a typo? and next time share your code eh

```css
html {
  font-family: lato; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>&larr; Medical Device Solutions</p>
   </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If you hit "Run code snippet", it shows the strange character instead of the arrow…